# Issue With BeautifulSoup (Cannot find ALL elements)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a website and its products. I wrote a script which returns the item name, price, and exact URL.

My issue is with these lines

```
containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ProductList-grid clear"})
print(len(containers))
# Output is ALWAYS 1
```

http://prntscr.com/kbq9mz

If you noticed from the screenshot, only 1 is printed out to console when in reality there should be 4 things being printed: http://prntscr.com/kbq6l3
I am unsure why it is only finding the first product but not the other 3.

Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
import requests

website = "https://www.revengeofficial.com"
session = requests.session()

urls_and_prices = {}


def get_items():
    response = session.get(website + "/webstore")
    soup = Bs(response.text, "html.parser")

    containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ProductList-grid clear"})
    print(len(containers))

    for div in containers:
        item_name = div.a["href"]
        get_price(website + item_name)


def get_price(item_url):
    response = session.get(item_url)
    soup = Bs(response.text, "html.parser")

    container = soup.find_all("section", {"class": "ProductItem-details"})

    for element in container:
        if element.div is not None:
            name = element.h1.text
            price = element.div.span.text
            urls_and_prices[item_url] = price


def print_item_info():
    if len(urls_and_prices) == 0:
        print("Could not find any items")
        return

    for key, value in urls_and_prices.items():
        name = key.split("/")[4]

        print("Item name: " + name)
        print("Price: " + value)
        print("Link: " + key)


get_items()
print_item_info()
```

I appreciate the help, thanks.

EDIT: Also, I'd appreciate criticism on my code. I am new to python and want to improve as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting entire grids and there is only 1 grid, select all the products instead by selecting with `ProductList-item`

```
soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ProductList-item"})
```

Comment: Ah, got ya. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This will find 4 items

```
containers = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "ProductList-item-link"})
print(len(containers))

for a in containers:
    item_name = a["href"]
    get_price(website + item_name)
```